# Array is empty after readline data is pushed

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, asynchronous, readline

I am trying to write a program, where I need  to read data from a file line by line synchronously, store values line by line in an array using `Array.push()`. I am reading the file using the `readline` npm package. However, when I try to call the array after iterating through the whole file, it shows me an empty array.

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    readline = require('readline'),
    stream = require('stream');

var instream = fs.createReadStream('sample.txt');
var outstream = new stream;
outstream.readable = true;
outstream.writable = true;
function printArray(ArrayVar){
    console.log(ArrayVar);
    }
function AddText(InputStream){
    var Text = new Array;
    var rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: instream,
        output: outstream,
        terminal: false
    });
    rl.on('line',function(line){
        Text.push(line);
    });
    return Text;
    }

var a = AddText(instream);
printArray(a);
```

I think I am having a problem because of the asynchronous execution of this code. How can I fix this and print the content of the array in proper order as in the text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen to the [`close`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_event_close) event and then print the array. `close` will be called once all lines have been read.

```
rl.on('close', function() {
   console.log(Text)
});
```

Also,

`var Text = new Array;`

Should be:

`var Text = new Array();`

or

`var Text = [];`

Comment: I just noticed the initialization. Is there any way I can use the `Text` variable outside that callback? Like, I am not able to assign that to any other variable. like create a global variable `MainArray` and write `MainArray = Text` in that callback. How can something of that fashion be done?

Comment: If I've understood what you mean, then you could move var Text = new Array(); out of the AddText() function which would make it accessible outside of AddText(). You still have to use the 'close' event to let other functions know when it was populated though.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait for the lines to be read before logging the variable(in your case its `Text`) value.
You must wait for all the lines to be read by listening on `close` event, or do something in `line` event itself.

Your code should look something like below

```
    var fs = require('fs'),
     readline = require('readline'),
     stream = require('stream');

    var instream = fs.createReadStream('sample.txt');
    var outstream = new stream;
    outstream.readable = true;
    outstream.writable = true;

    function printArray(ArrayVar){
        console.log(ArrayVar);
        }

    function AddText(InputStream){
        var Text = new Array;
        var rl = readline.createInterface({
            input: instream,
            output: outstream,
            terminal: false
        });

        rl.on('line',function(line){
            Text.push(line);
        });

        rl.on('close', function(){
            printArray(Text)
        })
        }

    var a = AddText(instream);
```

Also you are not using the parameter `InputStream` that you are passing to `AddText` function.

Comment: So how do I use the `Text` variable outside the callback. As in, cant I return it outside the event? I try to assign Text to a global variable but I am not able to.

Comment: When you try to print the variable, the value should be present in it. In your case, you get it empty coz, the `rl.on` is a event emitted by `readline` interface and it is emitted only after a line is read. You have to wait somehow till the variable gets filled, or call an function(like callback function) from within `rl.on('close'...)` to achieve your logic.

Comment: Also @dan was first to answer it correctly.  So if you are gonna accept the answer, it should be `dan`'s.

Comment: Thanks @Panther :)